# Decoding Plesk passwords

Tags: php, passwords, plesk, crypt, password-hash

First time question.

I have a customer panel that shows the Plesk 12.5 password. For now I put that in manually when I generate the password. But customers change their password, forget it and then everything fails. I use the Plesk API to receive the password, but this is encrypted.

`$5$CngpmNFXTsfRswHH$nntnTlj0KLkhEidK.XVWgbyv9HcAE8YV/fog0C6aG17`

I found out that the key is found in `/etc/psa/private/secret_key`.

I tried:

```
$res_non = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $hash, 'ecb');

$decrypted = $res_non;
$dec_s2 = strlen($decrypted);

$padding = ord($decrypted[$dec_s2-1]);
$decrypted = substr($decrypted, 0, -$padding);
```

But that doesn't return my password correctly.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: If its been done properly, you cannot get a password out of a hash. Just reset the password and give your users the new password

Comment: As far as I know this is not an hash. It is possible to decrypt it. It worked in Plesk 11 back then.

Comment: Surely they at least don't use [ecb](https://blog.filippo.io/content/images/2015/11/Tux_ecb.jpg) and an iv.

Comment: @PeeHaa no clue, That's what i try to find out :).]

Comment: Look into their source instead of guessing what they are doing.

Comment: Also when doing a simple google search I get several results like http://serverfault.com/a/425129/79155

Comment: I tried that one, but it doesn't work for Plesk 12.5. The Source code of Plesk is encrypted so I can't look into there code.

Comment: Well in that case I suggest asking plesk for support, because trying to guess encryption schemes is pretty much useless when done correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Way to decrypt it, indeed, exists, but it is not public, and, probably, it will never be. Even support doesn't know the way to decrypt it.
You can view passwords of mail users via mail_auth_view command. That's all that can be done.

Source - I've worked in Plesk dev for some time.

Comment: Alright, That's bloody annoying. Is it some propitiatory stuff? Or can i reset passwords trough the API?

Comment: @RamonJ.A.Smit You can reset passwords as you like via either API, or CLI, if you have admin access to server, of course.

Comment: I have admin access :-)

Comment: It's stored in Unix hash format (sha256crypt) - a hash, by definition, cannot be decrypted because it is one way, so therefore your initial statement is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [sha256crypt](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/lib/passlib.hash.sha256_crypt.html) hash, without storing the number of rounds (which means it's likely hard-coded). If so, [this isn't *encrypted*](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded). Hashing is not encryption. Hashing is a subtopic of cryptography, but is wholly separate from encryption.

- Hashing: one-way transformation of an infinite set of possible values to a value in a large but finite set of possible outputs. Keyless.
- Encryption: reversible transformation of information, secured by a secret key (and/or, in certain algorithms, a public key).

Please don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 1):

How about to reset password via "Forgot your password?" on login screen?